# patroni.exceptions.PatroniFatalException: 'Failed to bootstrap cluster'

Tags: centos7, postgresql, yaml, patroni

I have a problem with patroni right here

```
[postgres@localhost ~]$ patroni /etc/patroni.yml
2021-05-25 11:39:56,767 INFO: Selected new etcd server http://10.102.196.138:2379
2021-05-25 11:39:56,772 INFO: No PostgreSQL configuration items changed, nothing to reload.
2021-05-25 11:39:56,831 INFO: Lock owner: None; I am etcd1
2021-05-25 11:39:56,836 INFO: trying to bootstrap a new cluster
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.UTF-8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are enabled.

creating directory /data/patroni ... initdb: error: could not create directory "/data/patroni": Permission denied
pg_ctl: database system initialization failed
2021-05-25 11:39:56,877 INFO: removing initialize key after failed attempt to bootstrap the cluster
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/patroni", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/patroni/__init__.py", line 170, in main
    return patroni_main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/patroni/__init__.py", line 138, in patroni_main
    abstract_main(Patroni, schema)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/patroni/daemon.py", line 100, in abstract_main
    controller.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/patroni/__init__.py", line 108, in run
    super(Patroni, self).run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/patroni/daemon.py", line 59, in run
    self._run_cycle()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/patroni/__init__.py", line 111, in _run_cycle
    logger.info(self.ha.run_cycle())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/patroni/ha.py", line 1457, in run_cycle
    info = self._run_cycle()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/patroni/ha.py", line 1351, in _run_cycle
    return self.post_bootstrap()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/patroni/ha.py", line 1247, in post_bootstrap
    self.cancel_initialization()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/patroni/ha.py", line 1240, in cancel_initialization
    raise PatroniFatalException('Failed to bootstrap cluster')
patroni.exceptions.PatroniFatalException: 'Failed to bootstrap cluster'
```

Here is my patroni.yml

```
scope: postgres
namespace: /db/
name: etcd1

restapi:
    listen: 10.102.196.138:8008
    connect_address: 10.102.196.138:8008

etcd:
    hosts: 10.102.196.138:2379,10.102.196.139:2379,10.102.196.147:2379

bootstrap:
    dcs:
        ttl: 30
        loop_wait: 10
        retry_timeout: 10
        maximum_lag_on_failover: 1048576
        postgresql:
            use_pg_rewind: true

    initdb:
    - encoding: UTF8
    - data-checksums

    pg_hba:
    - host replication all 127.0.0.1/32 md5
    - host replication all 10.102.196.138/0 md5
    - host replication all 10.102.196.139/0 md5
    - host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5

    users:
        admin:
            password: admin
            options:
                - createrole
                - createdb
 postgresql:
    listen: 10.102.196.138:5432
    connect_address: 10.102.196.138:5432
    data_dir: /data/patroni
    pgpass: /tmp/pgpass
    authentication:
        replication:
            username: replicator
            password: password
        superuser:
            username: postgres
            password: password
    parameters:
        unix_socket_directories: '.'

tags:
    nofailover: false
    noloadbalance: false
    clonefrom: false
    nosync: false

[postgres@localhost ~]$ ls /data/
patroni_2021-05-25-11-03-59
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Did you have any new information about resolving your problem? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it might be a simple thing?

`could not create directory "/data/patroni": Permission denied`

Can you verify that the /data directory has the correct permissions for you to create directory?
Try going to the /data directory and run manually:

`$ mkdir patroni`